# Wear OS Android Studio background image

Tags: wear-os

[image]This might be the wrong site but it's hard to find the right one here.

I'm making wear os watch faces with Android Studio. I have the latest version and all updates. I followed a Code Lab tutorial to make my first watch face. Went smoothly more or less. It worked anyway. I've done a bit of Kotlin tutorials, developed a lot in the past but Z80A assembler and VB mostly.

All I did was add my own 512x512 png to the drawable folder, change the backgroundImageResource value to index that image instead and now whenever the watch hands move they leave lines behind and the watch face doesn't clear them until ambient mode...

I thought initially it would be the bit depth, all the default pngs are 24 bit and I'm using Affinity Photo which only seems to go as low as 32 bits so I can't test it but I don't want to go down that road until I have a better idea of what's happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turns out using Kotlin...any replacement background image must be called "background_image", not "my_image" or "that_image"...or any other correctly formed title.

I don't understand but as soon as I renamed my "storm_blue.png" to "background_image.png" and changed the drawable index...works fine!